# Sublime 3: remove all characters beyond a given column

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I'm using Sublime 3. I have a rather large file (~8000 lines) with the data arranged in columns.

I need to remove *all characters* beyond a given column, say column 95.

I tried selecting all lines with `Ctrl+Shift+L` to edit them all at once but Sublime chokes.

Is there a package to do this sort of task or should I just use some regex? If so, what regex command can I use?

Comment: Should be able to do `s/(.{1,95}).*/\1/`

Comment: O_O three downvotes in 2 seconds and not a single comment on why?

Comment: Because it's not a programming question. This would be better-asked in Superuser. It's also a soft request for a 3rd party module ("Is there a package to do this sort of task") which is off-topic by definition. That said, I feel like regex questions *of other sorts* are on-topic here, so if you re-word to just ask for a regex solution this should be fine

Comment: Ok. I've seen dozens of sublime and regex related questions here. I see many right now in the right column. Anyway, thanks for your comment but that command does not seem to work. It has no effect at all.

Comment: The off-topic flag says "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow **unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming**" - I'd say this is on-topic for that reason, and certainly for a question about regex

Comment: Use sed: http://superuser.com/questions/529345/remove-characters-from-column-n-until-end-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a regular expression, try:

```
/^(.{1,95}).*/\1/
```

In sublime this looks like:

```
Find What:    ^(.{1,95}).*
Replace With: $1
```

Comment: Thanks again Adam. That command selects the entire length of each line in the file.

Comment: @Gabriel it sure does!

Comment: Ok, I see now that the magic happens after replacing with `$1`. I was expecting to see only characters beyond column 95 selected by Sublime, which got me confused. Thank you Adam!